# How to combine results of two query from different tables?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have two tables:

1. Table_Shop:

   Fields: id, shopname, address, area_name, contact
2. Table_City:

   Fields: id, area_name (same as table_shop), city

Common Field in both tables: area_name

Now I want to search shop using area_name and city.
The first priority is area_name if there is less data available then it fetch by city.

E.g. [see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3PSk.png).

I want to fetch 3 records of mobile shop of a particular area such as 'river front', but here only 1 record is available, but I need 3, so remaining 2 records are come from a local city of river front which is ahmedabad. So I need to fetch next two records from station road, ahmedabad.

I tried to do this two different queries like below,

```
 $q1=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from Table_Shop where area_name='river front'"));

$tot_q1=count($q1);

if($tot_q1<3)

{

  $q2=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from Table_City where city='ahmedabad' and area_name!='river front'"));

// i add this line *area_name!='river front'* to stop duplicate value such as if river front(mobile shop) is already fetched then i dont need to fetch it again.

}

return $q1+q2;
```

but it is more complex when I implement paging in this code. How could I do this in a single query?

Comment: Just to be clear, you are trying to fetch data from two different queries?

Comment: use join instead of all multiple queries

Comment: try `return array_merge($q1+q2;)`

Comment: Yeah but i want this data using single query, because if i am using both query then at paging time it occurs problem so i want fetch using single query only is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
SELECT * from (
    SELECT table_shop.id, table_shop.shopname, table_shop.address, 
table_shop.area_name, table_city.city
        FROM table_shop
        JOIN table_city on table_shop.area_name = table_city.area_name
        WHERE area_name='river front'
    UNION
    SELECT table_shop.id, table_shop.shopname, table_shop.address, table_shop.area_name, table_city.city
        FROM table_shop
        JOIN table_city on table_shop.area_name = table_city.area_name
        WHERE area_name!='river front' 
            AND table_city.city='ahmedabad') limit 3
```

or

```
SELECT table_shop.id, table_shop.shopname, table_shop.address, 
table_shop.area_name, table_city.city
    FROM table_shop
    JOIN table_city on table_shop.area_name = table_city.area_name
    WHERE table_shop.area_name='river front' OR  table_city.city='ahmedabad'
    ORDER BY table_shop.area_name <> 'river front',
    priority 
    limit 3
```

Also, it is not a good idea to link the tables by `area_name`, a text column. I recommend you to create a third table,

```
area {id, name, city_id}
```

change `table_shop` to

```
shop {id, name, address, area_id, contact}
```

and change `table_city` to

```
city {id, name}
```

Also, prefixing tables with `table_` is redundant, so I would avoid it.

Answer (score -1):

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> drop table if exists table_shop;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.10 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> create table table_shop (id int,shopname varchar(20),areaname varchar(20));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.18 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> drop table if exists table_city;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> create table table_city (id int, areaname varchar(20), city varchar(20));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.19 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> insert into table_shop values
    -> (1,'Mob','station road'),(2,'food','river road'),(3,'cold drink','river road'),(4,'mob','river front'),
    -> (5,'rec','station road'),(6,'Mob','station road'),(7,'mob','station road'),(8,'ice','river road'),
    -> (9,'mob','river road');
Query OK, 9 rows affected (0.03 sec)
Records: 9  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> insert into table_city values
    -> (1,'station road','ahamabad'),(2,'river road','delhi'),(3,'river front','ahamabad');
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> select ts.id,ts.shopname, ts.areaname, tc.city, s.*
    -> from table_shop ts
    -> join table_city tc on tc.areaname = ts.areaname
    -> join
    -> (
    -> select  distinct ts.shopname, ts.areaname, tc.city
    -> from table_shop ts
    -> join table_city tc on tc.areaname = ts.areaname
    -> where ts.areaname = 'river front'
    -> ) s on s.shopname = ts.shopname and s.city = tc.city
    ->
    -> ;
+------+----------+--------------+----------+----------+-------------+----------+
| id   | shopname | areaname     | city     | shopname | areaname    | city     |
+------+----------+--------------+----------+----------+-------------+----------+
|    1 | Mob      | station road | ahamabad | mob      | river front | ahamabad |
|    4 | mob      | river front  | ahamabad | mob      | river front | ahamabad |
|    6 | Mob      | station road | ahamabad | mob      | river front | ahamabad |
|    7 | mob      | station road | ahamabad | mob      | river front | ahamabad |
+------+----------+--------------+----------+----------+-------------+----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```